# Word 365 Page Boundaries through Macro

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have been missing for a long time the page boundaries, that have been removed by MS a couple of years ago. I found at: [How do I show the page margin in Word 2016?](https://superuser.com/questions/1286876/how-do-i-show-the-page-margin-in-word-2016/1360252#1360252?newreg=fedb9a87b5ff40649dd3349d28c16676) a Macro (I cannot comment there direclty, not enough frequent flyer miles here), that turns them on. However, the question is: how do I turn them off again?
The issue is, that when I uncommented the line:
' ActiveDocument.GridOriginFromMargin = True
As suggested in the post, it created a checkered page like here: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBkGE.png) .
How do I get rid of this? I cannot quite figure this out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, silly me, I figured it out. I need to get back into Windows Macros at some point.

All it took was a Options.DisplayGridLines = False towards the end, and the grid lines went away.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

The VBA command you are looking for is:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowCropMarks = True
```

In Office 365 the option is available on the **File > Options > Advanced** dialog.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that option, but it is not quite what I was looking for (and aparently quite a few others). The crop marks show "crosses" at the corners of the text boundaries, but they don't show the text boundaries themselfes (if that makes sense).
However - my initial question here is still: how do I now get rid of those ugly squares / checkers? A bit annoying and I feel really stupid...

Comment: Do you want page borders visible in the printed document?  It's not completely clear what you're trying to do or what you want a completed document to look like.

Comment: sorry, if I am not clear. Forget about Word options.

The problem is that I have used the Macro from: https://superuser.com/questions/1286876/how-do-i-show-the-page-margin-in-word-2016/1360252#1360252?newreg=fedb9a87b5ff40649dd3349d28c16676

Now, all my Word documents are checkered, like in the screenshot above.

How do I get rid of them checkers?

Thanks